# gnu cgi (cgicc) does not compile with gcc on Windows using MinGW/Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cgi, cygwin, mingw

I have to build a "proof of concept" using cgicc on Windows. But currently I am unable to build cgicc. The current release of cgicc v3.2.9 won't build neither in MinGW (gcc v4.5.0 / v3.4.5) nor Cygwin (gcc v4.3.4-3).

By using gcc v3.4.5 and automake in MinGW I got:

> HTMLAttributeList.cpp:51: internal compiler error: in rest_of_handle_final, at toplev.c:2067
> Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.

Using gcc v4.3.4 and automake gives for Cygwin:

> In file included from CgiEnvironment.cpp:36:
> ../cgicc/CgiEnvironment.h:52: error: explicit instantiation of 'class std::vector<cgicc::HTTPCookie, std::allocator<cgicc::HTTPCookie> >' in namespace 'cgicc'
> which does not enclose namespace 'std')

and for gcc v4.5.0 in MinGW:

> ../cgicc/CgiEnvironment.h:52:33: error: explicit instantiation of 'class std::vector<cgicc::HTTPCookie>' in namespace 'cgicc' (which does not enclose namespace
> 'std')

I tried to ignore the Automake and Autoconf scripts. I set up Eclipse-CDT for using the apropriate compiler switches (I also tried Code::Blocks):

> -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWIN32 -I.. -Wall -W -pedantic -g -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -DCGICC_EXPORTS

But again I got:

> explicit instantiation of 'class std::vector<cgicc::HTTPCookie, std::allocator<cgicc::HTTPCookie> >' in namespace 'cgicc' (which does not enclose namespace 'std')    CgiEnvironment.h    /cgicc/cgicc    line 52

CgiEnvironment.h:51 to line 53 contains the ifdef WIN32:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

namespace cgicc {
...
#ifdef WIN32
  template class CGICC_API std::vector<HTTPCookie>;
#endif
...
}
```

What goes wrong? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can compile cgicc. Thanks to a very good friend of mine, Vlad Lazarenko and some hours of investigation. But I have to do some major changes.

My friend helped me to go on the right way by understanding the main issue. He and Vlad Lazarenko gave me a good direction to investigate the `__declspec()`. This is a feature of Microsoft compilers which are [now supported in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

During investigation I stumbled over a post with [migration hints for GCC3.4.3 to GCC4.1.2](http://readlist.com/lists/gcc.gnu.org/gcc-help/2/14088.html). So I moved the explicit instantiation of the templates behind the declared namespace in following headers:

> Cgicc.h
>   CgiEnvironment.h
>   HTMLAttributeList.h
>   HTMLElementList.h

Next I discovered a strange behaviour while checking different compiler switches and other things regarding my build environment. During investigatiopn of cgicc header files the defined `-DCGICC_EXPORTS` becomes sometimes undefined (expansion is shown by Eclipse CDT). So I changed `CgiDefs.h` from:

```
// export library symbols
#ifdef CGICC_EXPORTS
#  define CGICC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define CGICC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

to

```
#  define CGICC_API __declspec(dllimport)
```

At the end I changed the compiler switches to
`-DWIN32 -DCGICC_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu++98`. Most important is `-std=gnu++98`. Without gnu extensions `__declspec()` wont generate any symbols - even for a static library. I do not understand why I need that for a static library because the symbols should be in their object files which are packet into `libcgicc.a`.

Now some further questions:

1. Do anyone know a mechanism how `CGICC_EXPORTS` can became undefined
   without 
   `#undef CGICC_EXPORTS` and without `-UCGICC_EXPORTS`?
2. Why I have to use gnu extensions? I thought the defaults are independend.
3. Why do I have to use `__declspec(dllexport)` for a static library?
4. Why it is not enough to use the object files of a static library? Let me ask the same 
   in a different way: Why are no symbols found if I try to link object files of a static 
   library?
5. What is the advantage/disadvantage of "implicit template instantiation and vague
   linkage" versus "explicit template instantiation"?

Answer (score 0):

The `CGICC_API` should be either defined as `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`.
It looks like that `DLL_EXPORT` macro that gets defined in command line should affect that, but it doesn't.
My guess is that some header handling it is not included. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y1sfaz2.aspx) and [that](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/01/18/dll-export-cxx-templates/) for more information.

Comment: This is done in file CgiDefs.h which is included by the header files of the affected class files. By the way, how can I add code to this text box by using code tags?


<pre><code>
...
#ifdef WIN32
// export library symbols
#  ifdef CGICC_EXPORTS
#    define CGICC_API __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define CGICC_API __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
...
</code></pre>